# ACF Pro breaks linked product section in admin woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Advanced custom field pro plugin breaks linked product section in admin. Search doesn't work when I activate that plugin and also existing selected products also don't show up.

I searched on this but no solution found. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
[image: Not working with ACF Pro]
[image: Working without ACF Pro]

Comment: No error message, nothing. I tried debugging theme and all plugins. THat's how I came to know that its ACF Pro causing issue. And that's what I know.

Comment: I have woocommerce (2.6.14), wp (4.7.3) and I have 51 other plugins.

Comment: @Kirk you are correct! There are no console errors. Let me try removing those product groups !

Comment: I highly doubt it's only the combination ACF + WooCommerce. Its probably due another plugin (and 51... thats quite a lot). If you disable all other plugins except WooCommerce + ACF and revert to a default theme... is the problem still there? We use ACF + WooCommerce in a dozen of sites with no issues.

Comment: @Kirk Beard I removed all product groups but it didn't work. I believe that its some js issue. Because when I click on "Linked Product" the script should initiate an ajax. (which doesn't trigerr when I activate ACF Pro)

Comment: I understand. But there is no console error. I debugged further and it seems its conflicting with Shortcode UI as well.

Comment: @Kirk thanks for your assistance. I fixed it from shortcode UI. It loads select2 jquery one more time. That creates issue.(But it does not give any js error)

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue today too. I was on ACF 5.3.x and WooCommerce 3.0.3.

I updated ACF to current version 5.5.11. This required an update to the WP database. Also, I had neglected to update the WP database after 3.0.3.

**Updating ACF and the WP database resolved my issue.**

*Just a note: Another problem that this fixed was the composite product>add component options. They were previously not loading.*

Comment: @VidishPurohit Just gave that a try but since I'm a new user I guess the upvote isn't publicly displayed. Need to get some more rep. Thanks for the string!